# Prevent mmenu with cloning enabled to clone CSS classes

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, mmenu

I have a menu structured like this:

```
<nav id="header-bar-menu-wrapper" class="show-for-large">
        <ul id="header-bar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="">Link 1</a>
          </li>
```

And cloned with mmenu like this:

```
var $menu = $("#header-bar-menu-wrapper").mmenu({
    // options
}, {
    // configuration
    clone: true
});
```

I want the original menu to be visible on desktop and to use mmenu only on tablet/mobile.

Since I use Zurb Foundation, I'd like to use the provided classes to do this and not write my own media queries. This is why I use `show-for-large`.

However, `show-for-large` is copied over to the cloned menu which looks like this:

```
<nav id="mm-header-bar-menu-wrapper" class="show-for-large mm-menu mm-menu_offcanvas mm-menu_opened">
```

How can I prevent CSS classes to be cloned over?

Alternatively, how can I use Foundation's own breakpoints to do this? I don't want to write any pixel size in my own CSS.

I'd also like to avoid having to add/remove the class via JavaScript, though I'm forced to do so right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$("#header-bar-menu-wrapper").clone().removeClass('show-for-large').mmenu({
    // options
}, {
    // configuration
})
```